# Extracting String between 2 Strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract a string that located between 2 other strings in a file 
The strings are "USE" and "GO"

and this is what i came out with :

```
$importPath = "SOMEPATH"
$pattern = "(?<=\*\*USE\*\*)[\s\S]*(?=\*\*GO\*\*)"

Get-Content $importPath | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) { $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)}}

$arr
```

But when executing this I get nothing

Example SQL Script :

```
USE FIZNET
GO



DECLARE @Symbol_Type_Id SMALLINT

SELECT @Symbol_Type_Id = Symbol_Type_Id 
FROM dbo.SymbolTypes 
WHERE SymbolType = 'Indices - Asia'

UPDATE dbo.Currencies SET
Symbol_Type_Id = @Symbol_Type_Id
WHERE Currency = 'ASX'

GO
```

I would like the $arr to have the value "FIZNET"

Comment: Do you have a sample string and expected output for comparison? Also in your example you have `$path` put use `Get-Content $importPath`. Are you sure the source file is being read and that it contains the lines that should match?

Comment: Thanks for the Edit ,it is $importPath is both places , and i verified the file is in the location ,
its a simple SQL Script i`m trying to extract the Database name from , the string will be from the Type :  USE [DB NAME] GO 
And i like to extract the DB NAME so i know where to execute the script (different DB`s located in different servers)

Comment: You have no asterisks in your sample

Comment: Are USE and GO on the same line... do they repeat multiple times in the file.? Please include a scrubbed sample of the file.

Comment: Added Example , Thank You

Comment: Updated my answer with your sample and my code still works. Just the "***" you have are not required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.*` regex to match all strings. For example:

```
$importPath = "PATHNAME"
$pattern = "USE(.*)GO"

$string = Get-Content $importPath
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result
```

Comment: This wont work, since it is greedy, if there are multiple matches in the file. Should wait for op to include sample data.

Comment: Example Added to Original Post , Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, this might be of help:

```
$Result = 'SELECT USE SELECT * FROM MyTable GO OTHER STUFF' -split 'USE|GO' |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1

# Remove space before and after
$Result.Trim()
```

The output is:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Comment: The output would have a leading and trailing space would it not?

Answer (score 0):

There is room for improvement here since we don't have a sample file but your regex pattern appears to function for something like this.

```
**USE**AdventureWorks2012**GO**
```

I suspect that is not how the lines look in your data file. Possibly that is split across lines? I would like to introduce you to `Select-String` to help mitigate this. Consider the following file of bad sql (for testing) I created from [TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx).

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
DECLARE @MyMsg VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @MyMsg = 'Hello, World.'
GO -- @MyMsg is not valid after this GO ends the batch. Just because.

**USE** AdventureWorks2012;
**GO**
DECLARE @MyMsg VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @MyMsg = 'Hello, World.'
```

Now, in that file we have an example that has asterisks and one that does not. Your regex is expecting `**` so I have included solutions to cover both scenarios.

```psh
# Test with one pattern and comment out the other
$pattern = "(?<=USE\*\*)([\s\S]*?)(?=\*\*GO)"
$pattern = "(?<=USE)([\s\S]*?)(?=GO)"

(Get-Content $path -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches -CaseSensitive).Matches.Value | ForEach-Object{$_.Trim()}
```

Use the `$pattern` that actually matches your text. If it does spread across lines this will work as we read the file in as one string (Would be slow with large files). `-CaseSensitive` should help in case there is a comment in the text that had the word "because" for instance. Another important change is that the match was made *non*-greedy in case there are multiple matches in the file.

Patterns should return `AdventureWorks2012;` and `AdventureWorks2012` respectively.

## Edit with your sample

Using the following code based on my explanation above you get your expected results.

```
$pattern = "(?<=USE)([\s\S]*?)(?=GO)"
$arr = (Get-Content $path -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches -CaseSensitive).Matches.Value | ForEach-Object{$_.Trim()}
```