# Extract multiline text between two words from a file

Tags: powershell

I have found the results using the following URLs but not finding the multiple verification in the whole file.  I mean it's checking only one time and not checking for multiple searches.  This is sample code which I have and require to find in between `create procedure`, `end`.

```
create procedure DummyProc
as
begin

    set nocount on 
select * from emp
end
insert into values emp
end
create procedure emp
as
begin
    set nocount on
update from employee
end
```

The URLs which I have checked are:

- [Extracting String between 2 Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759261/extracting-string-between-2-strings)
- [powershell extract text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746272/powershell-extract-text-between-two-strings)

Comment: *I mean it's checking only one time and not checking for multiple searches* - what is checking only one time?

Comment: Checking in between words create procedure and end.  The scripts are checking only one time in text file and it's give the result and not checking other data in a file